Tile according to a pattern in pytorch (or numpy)?
I have a 2-d tensor pattern I'd like to repeat/tile with a particular sparsity. I suspect there is a function (or two-line approach using gather, fold/unfold, or similar) to do this in Pytorch.
These two approaches each get the result I want but are inefficient and/or confusing:
# inputs
mask = torch.rand(5, 5) > .7
pattern = torch.rand(4, 4)

# approach a (brute force):
result_a = torch.zeros(20, 20)
for i in range(5):
  for j in range(5):
    if mask[i][j]:
       result_a[i*4: (i+1)*4, j*4: (j+1)*4] = pattern

# approach b (interpolate the binary mask)
tiled_pattern = torch.tile(pattern, (5, 5))
bigger_mask = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(mask.view(1, 1, *mask.shape).to(torch.float16), scale_factor=(4, 4), mode='area').squeeze((0, 1))
result_b = torch.mul(tiled_pattern, bigger_mask)

In particular, I don't like approach (b) because the interpolate function needs me to cast the input, add and remove two dimensions, and I don't trust the 'area' mode to always work--it's not even really defined in the Pytorch documentation.
Is there a cleaner way to do this? If not in Pytorch, than in Numpy (or another common Python package?)

Start with a (25,4,4) result_a and a (25,) mask. result_a[mask,:,:] = pattern. Should also work with a (5,5,4,4), but the 3d is easier to visualize. Conversion to (20,20) will require a transpose.

You can do this simply with a broadcasted multiply, in both torch and numpy.
result_c = (mask[:, None, :, None] * pattern[None, :, None, :]).reshape(20, 20)


This is cleaner than either of my solutions, and is a one-liner--thank you! Accepting this answer

You can use slices to fill the matrix by mask. Then use 2d convolution to solve your problem.
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
mask=np.random.rand(5,5)>.7
pattern=np.random.rand(4,4)
result=np.zeros((20,20))
result[1::4,1::4]=mask
result=convolve2d(result, pattern, mode='same')

